# Select multiple classes with the same parent

Tags: javascript, css, styles, stylesheet, rule

Let's say I have the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <span class="first"></span>
        <span class="second"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to create a CSS rule that affects both `.first` and `.second`. I could do the following:

```
#container #content .first, #container #content .second { font-weight: bold; }
```

But is there a way to shorten this? Such as:

```
#container #content .[first|second] { font-weight: bold; }
```

Of course in this example, I don't save too many characters, but I've had real instances where it'd be helpful to shorten it like this.

So, is something like this possible? I've searched around and couldn't find anything, but I'm hoping that there's some way to accomplish this? An extreme way would be to use something like JavaScript, I guess.

Comment: just use `.first, .second`

Comment: @brouxhaha in that case you would also match instances of class `second` not contained in `#container #content`

Comment: That's true, but if they differ in other divs, I would recommend using a different class.

Comment: My situation assumes that there are other elements with the same classes outside of the DIVs that I want, and that I can't change the class names. Otherwise, I'd definitely re-arrange a few class and ID names to make things easier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since IDs must be unique, you can simplify it to this:

```css
#content .first, #content .second
```

CSS3 offers `:matches`:

```css
#content :matches(.first, .second)
```

However, as you can see, it's no shorter! Plus it's still new, so older browsers don't support it.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a good option. However, I use Firefox, and the latest release version does not implement :matches just yet. It calls it -moz-any, rather. So I can use that for now, although I'll have to remember to change it to :matches once that's added.

Comment: If you're adding vendor prefixes, you end up with longer CSS selectors than if you just used the plain stuff in the first place ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, on it's own there is no way to do something like this in CSS, however there are things called CSS prepocessors which make behavior like this possible. Using a preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) you would often write something along the lines of

```
 #container #content{
  /* css specific for this element */
  .first,.second{
   /* css specific for elements with class first or second contained in #container #content
  }
 }
```

The downside is that you need to either execute javascript on the client side or run the preprocessor every time you change your css on the server side. There are a couple of automated workflows for this, but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Since ID's must be unique there is no need to using `#container #content`.

You could use a "direct child selector":

```
#content > span
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GJHPP/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not add another class?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <span class="first important"></span>
        <span class="second important"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use the single selector:

```
.important { font-weight: bold; }
```